# MYSQL case inside date_format function

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to put a case statement inside a date_format function? I have been trying to do this in MYSQL but it keeps telling me about a syntax error on the open parenthesis '(' between date_format and case.

```
SELECT date_format(
  case when h.load_terms='FCL' 
  then dd_fcl.delivery_date 
  else dd_lcl.delivery_date end
,'%Y %M %D') as del_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the from clause in your query. Please do provide the source table name from which you wish to fetch the data.